# Let clause nested in if clause nested in do clause

Tags: haskell

I'm currently working my way through Learn You a Haskell for Great Good, and I'm trying to modify one of the code snippets in chapter nine, "Input and Output" to handle errors correctly:

```
main = do
    (command:args) <- getArgs
    let result = lookup command dispatch
    if result == Nothing
        then
            errorExit 
        else
            let (Just action) = result
    action args
```

where

```
dispatch :: [(String, [String] -> IO ())]
```

is an association list

and

```
errorExit :: IO ()
```

is some function that prints an error message.

Compiling this with GHC gives the error message

```
todo.hs:20:13: parse error in let binding: missing required 'in'
```

which (to my understanding), seems to be saying that the "let" here doesn't realise it's in a "do" block.

Adding "do" on lines five and seven (after "then" and "else" respectively), changes the error message to

```
todo.hs:20:13:
The last statement in a 'do' block must be an expression
  let (Just action) = result

todo.hs:21:5: Not in scope: `action'.
```

and now, whilst I agree with the first error message, I also have that one of my variables has jumped out of scope? I've double checked my alignment, and nothing seems to be out of place.

What is the appropriate way to assign a varaible within an if clause that is within a do block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@svenningsson suggested the right fix.  The reason your original fails is because `let` *clauses* can only appear at the top level of a `do` block - they're simple syntactic sugar that doesn't look into inner expressions:

```
do let x = 1
   y
```

desugars to the `let` *expression*

```
let x = 1 in y
```

Alas, in a `do` block, an *expression* clause like `if ... then ... else ...` has no way to declare variables in the rest of the `do` block at all.

There are at least two possible ways to get around this.

1. Absorb the remainder of the `do` block *into* the expression:

   ```
   main = do
       (command:args) <- getArgs
       let result = lookup command dispatch
       if result == Nothing
           then
               errorExit 
           else do
               let (Just action) = result
               action args
   ```

   (This is essentially the method @svenningsson uses in his better `case` version too.)

   This can however get a bit awkward if the remainder of the `do` expression needs to be duplicated into more than one branch.

   ("Secret" trick: GHC (unlike standard Haskell) doesn't actually require a final, inner `do` block to be indented more than the outer one, which can help if the amount of indentation starts getting annoying.)
2. Pull the variable declaration *outside* the expression:

   ```
   main = do
       (command:args) <- getArgs
       let result = lookup command dispatch
       action <- if result == Nothing
           then
               errorExit 
           else do
               let (Just action') = result
               return action'
       action args
   ```

   Here that requires making up a new variable name, since the pattern in the `let` clause isn't just a simple variable.

Finally, `action` was *always* out of scope in the last line of your code, but GHC works in several stages, and if it aborts in the parsing stage, it won't check for scope errors. (For some reason it does the `The last statement in a 'do' block must be an expression` check at a later stage than parsing.)

Addendum: After I understood what @Sibi meant, I see that `result == Nothing` isn't going to work, so you cannot use `if ... then ... else ...` with that even with the above workarounds.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to not use `if` in the first place, use `case`. By using `case` you get to test the value and bind the result to a variable all in one go. Like this:

```
main = do
    (command:args) <- getArgs
    case lookup command dispatch of
      Nothing -> errorExit
      Just action -> action args
```

For a more in-depth discussion on why we should prefer `case` over `if` see [boolean blindness](https://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/boolean-blindness/).

Comment: That's a much cleaner way of writing it, thanks. Also, I hadn't heard of Boolean blindness before! Do you know why my version doesn't work though?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error because you are trying to compare values of function type. When you perform the check `if result == Nothing`, it tries to check the equality of `Nothing` with the value of `result` which is a type of `Maybe ([String] -> IO ())`.

So, if you want it to properly typecheck, you have to define `Eq` instances for `->` and that wouldn't make any sense as you are trying to compare two functions for equality.

You can also use `fmap` to write your code:

```
main = do
    (command:args) <- getArgs
    let result = lookup command dispatch
    print $ fmap (const args) result
```

Comment: Um, I think you've miscalculated `result`'s type, it's a `Maybe`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Ah yeah, fixed it.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood what you meant, too. Although I don't think the OP's original code got to the type checking stage. Also, I don't think `print $ fmap ...` will do what they meant. You need at least something like `traverse_`.